# Subracting the nearest inputs to set it's value on another input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project. I wanted to subtract the value of the begbal input box and the nearest amtcoll input box and put the result on the nearest endbal inputbox.

My HTML code is:

```
<tr>
<td><input type="number" name="amtcoll[]" id="amtcoll" class="form-control text-right" value="2000.00"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="begbal[]" id="begbal" class="form-control text-right" value="0.00"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="endbal[]" id="endbal" class="form-control text-right" value="0.00"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="number" name="amtcoll[]" id="amtcoll" class="form-control text-right" value="1000.00"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="begbal[]" id="begbal" class="form-control text-right" value="0.00"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="endbal[]" id="endbal" class="form-control text-right" value="0.00"></td>
</tr>
```

And my JavaScript so far I use is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("input[name^=begbal]").change(function() {
                $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=endbal]").value =  $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=begbal]").value - $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=amtcoll]").value;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I wanted to as I type on the begbal input the result of subtraction will be passed on to the nearest endbal. But there is no value passed on the nearest endbal input. Please help. I can get how can I solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the value of input you need use `val` not `value`

```
$("input[name^=begbal]").change(function () {
  $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=endbal]").val( $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=begbal]").val() - $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=amtcoll]").val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks dude! That's why I cannot get a value.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery("input[name^=begbal]").on('input', function() {
    var amtVal = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=amtcoll]").val();
    var begalVal = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=begbal]").val();
    $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=endbal]").val(parseInt(begalVal - amtVal));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - here's another, which avoids going too far up and down the DOM.  Note - you should not have two elements with the same ID.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[class^=begbal]").change(function() {
    var endbal = $(this).val() - $(this).prev('.amtcoll').val();
    $(this).next('.endbal').val(endbal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="amtcoll[]" class="amtcoll" class="form-control text-right" value="2000.00">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="begbal[]" class="begbal" class="form-control text-right" value="0.00">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="endbal[]" class="endbal" class="form-control text-right" value="0.00">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="amtcoll[]" class="amtcoll" class="form-control text-right" value="1000.00">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="begbal[]" class="begbal" class="form-control text-right" value="0.00">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="endbal[]" class="endbal" class="form-control text-right" value="0.00">
  </td>
</tr>
```